# webview is broken when I load another page on Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron

I have two buttons. Each one has a link for a youtube video.
If I do not click on the video to play after it appears in the webview, I can change the src of webview by clicking on another button and I can see the image of the other video appears in the window. But if I click on either one and play the video, when I try to click on another button to see the another video, the webview is broken and all black and do not show me the video.

I tried too reload the window on standard menu of Electron, and the window   is blank. Same behavior only If I play one video. How can I fix it?

Electron version: 1.2.2
Operating system: Ubuntu 16.04

**[New info]**

I tested on Windows now and it works, but on Ubuntu the strange behavior happens.

**[Video showing the error]**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADoJGvNyJ7E

If you want to reproduce this behavior and check the code, here's the repository on github:

https://github.com/daltonmenezes/electron-error-example

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask | http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What does "reproduce the video" mean?

Comment: This might be your issue: https://discuss.atom.io/t/webview-loadurl-is-not-a-function/26485 define your click handlers after a `dom-ready` event.

Comment: @mostruash I'm sorry. I edited this topic for better comprehension. About your link, its different. Please, If you can, test my code on my repository for better comprehension. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about the hardware acceleration on linux distributions. The solution to fix it:

```
if (process.platform === 'linux') {
    app.disableHardwareAcceleration();
}
```